# Spring Java Google Cloud Storage: Handling number of retries and Delay

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-storage, spring-cloud

I'm wondering if it is possible to handle the the number of retries and the delay applied to them at Java code level GCS.

I know as per documentation, it is possible modifying `num_retries` and `max_retry_delay` variables at "[Boto]" section of the .boto config file (as it is described here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/RetryHandlingStrategy).

But I would like to achieve the same at Java code level or Spring Config. Is it even possible?

Comment: AFAIK, no, but why do you need this? Doyou have lot of issuu when writing to GCS?

Comment: Not really, I just need to retry certain amount of times as per business requirements. No 23 times. But if there is no way, then no way.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your retry settings using an API extension called [gax-java](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-java). The library contains a package called `com.google.api.gax.retrying` which is related to retrying API calls.

If you look at the docs, [`StorageOptions.Builder`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/StorageOptions.Builder.html) inherits a method called `setRetrySettings()` which accepts
`RetrySettings`.

You can use this sample code from [this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage/issues/26) to use internal retries:

```
RetrySettings retrySettings = RetrySettings
  .newBuilder()
  .setMaxAttempts(50)
  .setInitialRetryDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
  .setRetryDelayMultiplier(1.5)
  .setMaxRetryDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
  .build();
storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setRetrySettings(retrySettings).setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

....
```

Be aware of the following notes from the issue:

> Retrying mechanism is designed to handle timeouts from data transferring, network issues or access denied problems are out of scope of its responsibility. It also won't protect you from temporary network disconnections.

As additional reference, here's a [GitHub link](https://github.com/googleapis/java-core/blob/313193509ee7fa0e694188f9266c54c029a582c6/google-cloud-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/ServiceOptions.java#L728) to see the default retry settings.